# How to remove hashtag, user mentions & URLs from tweet. Twitter4j library(sentiment analysis) does not work properly with these noise words

Tags: url, twitter4j, sentiment-analysis, hashtag, tweets

How to remove hashtag, user mentions & URLs from tweet. Twitter4j library(sentiment analysis) does not work properly with these noise words

Example:
Tweet: Hello great morning today #summermorning @evilpriest @holysinner https://goo.le/asxmo/dataload.......

Should look like - 
Hello great morning today summermorning

Is there any method or utility available in twitter4J itself or we need to write our own? Please guide.

Comment: You need to write your own method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regular expressions to filter out the #es before parsing a sentence through the sentiment analysis pipeline!
Use this:

```
String withoutHashTweet = originalTweet.replaceAll("[#]", "");
```

So "Hello great morning today #summermorning @evilpriest @holysinner " should return : "Hello great morning today summermorning @evilpriest @holysinner"

Similarly replace the hash in the code with @ to remove the respective sign

Answer (score 0):

Something like that :

```js
let tweet = "@arthurlacoste check this link : http://lit.ly/hugeLink ! so #nsfw";

tweet = tweet.replace(/(?:https?|ftp):\/\/[\n\S]+/g, '') // remove links
        //.replace(/\#\w\w+\s?/g, '') remove hashtags words
        .replace('#', '') // remove hashtags only
        .replace(/\@\w\w+\s?/g, '');  // remove mentions

console.log(tweet);

// output : "check this link :  ! so nsfw"
```